# If there are two constructors in a class and both hold a double value but for diffrent purposes?

Tags: java

eg:

```
public class MathEquation{

    private double number1;
    private double number2;

    public MathEquation(double number1){
        this.number1 = number1*2;
    }

    public MathEquation(double number2){
        this.number2 = number2*2;
    }
}
```

Now if in our main class we write:

```
MathEquation display = new MathEquation(200.0d);
```

So, which constructor will be assigned the value 200.0d.
I know we can concat these two constructors in one but I just want to know if somehow this situation arises then what to do?

Comment: This code won't pass compilation.

Comment: Try compiling the code and you'll find out.

Comment: This whole thing is giving an error and saying that MathEquation(double) is already defined in the package.

Comment: Exactly. So there is no question here to answer.

Comment: I am using intellij ide.

Comment: I know that but if there are circumstances that i have to perform these two operations but not together than what to do.                                           If thats not the question it is .

Comment: This smells like an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: It doesn't matter what circumstances may arise. You can't compile this code, and therefore you cannot even write it, or design it. If your circumstances dictate otherwise there is something seriously wrong with those circumstances. It doesn't matter what IDE you are using. Your code is not valid Java. No IDE will compile it, and no Java compiler either. 'If that's not the question it is' is meaningless.

Comment: @EJP I suspect OP is asking for advice about what to do in the case where they _need_ two different ways of initialising an object, both with one double.  So possible answers might be things like (i) always pass two `Double` values, but one could be null (ii) pass an additional boolean or even an enum, indicating which meaning is intended, (iii) have initialisation methods that _aren't_ actually constructors, and have different names. And so on. I think OP knows that the code shown here won't compile.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem The trouble is that he *isn't* asking that. He should. He needs to back up several steps and ask how this mental tangle can ever get started.

Comment: "*if there are circumstances that i have to perform these two operations but not together than what to do*" proper answer depends on circumstances. To get real answer describe real problem (what you really want to achieve). For now your example is oversimplification which doesn't help us in helping you.

Comment: @EJP,@DawoodibnKareem

Comment: @EJP,@DawoodibnKareem ,@Pshemo                          I am a beginner and I am currently learning java through online courses and these are some of my doubts which I am unable to resolve through my one particular session on the constructor, that is why I asked.As the course is not live to me I could not question the tutor that's why I posted it here.

Comment: Please help me resolving the issue or make me understand the problem or mistake that I've made asking the question instead of being angry at me.Nobody is perfect at the very first time.But I've made my attempt.

Comment: StackOverflow has blocked me for 7 days due to some mischief in the comments but I feel that I have not done anything that wrong to be blocked.

Answer (score 2):

> which constructor will be assigned the value 200.0d.

Neither. The code will not compile.

> I just want to know if somehow this situation arises

It can't.

Answer (score 0):

I can't recommend it, but here is something you could do:

```
public class MathEquation {
    public MathEquation(Double d1, Double d2){
        if (d1 != null)
            number1 = d1;
        if (d2 != null)
            number2 = d2;
        if (d1==null && d2 == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}

// construct with just numbber1
MathEquation e1 = new MathEquation(20.0, null);
// construct with just number2
MathEquation e2 = new MathEquation(null, 30.0);
// construct wit both number1 and number2
MathEquation e3 = new MathEquation(20.0, 30.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

As described in the comments, you can't do this. It simply won't compile.

This is because overloads are resolved purely by class name, method name and parameter *types*. These constructors have the same class name, method name (constructors have the special name `<init>`) and parameter types, so they are *overload equivalent*. You can't have two overload equivalent methods in a class.

You can do something similar to this using *static factory methods* (a static method, often in the same class, which returns an instance of the class):

```
public static MathEquation forNumber1(double number1){
    return new MathEquation(number1*2, 0);
}

public static MathEquation forNumber2(double number2){
    return new MathEquation(0, number2*2);
}
```

Provided you also define a constructor:

```
MathEquation(double number1, double number2) {
  this.number1 = number1;
  this.number2 = number2;
}
```

These are not overload equivalent because they have different method names. In fact, one of the advantages of static factory methods (Item 1 in *Effective Java*) is that they act like "named constructors".

Then you simply invoke like any other static method:

```
MathEquation n1 = MathEquation.forNumber1(2);
MathEquation n2 = MathEquation.forNumber2(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments already, there are several ways to achieve what you want, but it won't work with two identical constructors. I'll highlight two options.

### Use the Builder design patttern

The [Builder design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) uses an additional object whose sole purpose is to build the object that you need. In your case, your class would look like this:

```
public class MathEquation{

    private final double number1;
    private final double number2;

    public static class Builder {

        private double number1;
        private double number2;

        private Builder() {}

        public Builder setNumber1(final double number1) {
            this.number1 = number1;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setNumber2(final double number2) {
            this.number2 = number2;
            return this;
        }

        public MathEquation build() {
            return new MathEquation(number1, number2);
        }
    }

    private MathEquation(final double number1, final double number2) {
        this.number1 = number1*2;
        this.number2 = number2*2;
    }

    public static Builder builder() {
        return new Builder();
    }

    // getter methods go here
}
```

Now, to create your object, you can do the following:

```
final MathEquation m = MathEquation.builder()
                                   .setNumber1(100.0d)
                                   .build();
```

or this:

```
final MathEquation m = MathEquation.builder()
                                   .setNumber2(100.0d)
                                   .build();
```

or even this:

```
final MathEquation m = MathEquation.builder()
                                   .setNumber1(100.0d)
                                   .setNumber2(100.0d)
                                   .build();
```

Now this is just a silly example, but in general terms, the Builder pattern can help you build complex objects, where using only constructors would cause confusion. Take, for example, the following constructors:

```
public class MyObject {

    // some variable declarations

    public MyObject(final String protocol, final String host, final String path, final String query) {
        // code goes here
    }

    public MyObject(final String protocol, final String host, final String path) {
        // code goes here
    }

    public MyObject(final String protocol, final String host) {
        // code goes here
    }
```

With only three constructors, you already need to look at the JavaDoc to see what all the fields do. But with the Builder pattern, you could do the following:

```
final MyObject instance = MyObject.builder()
                                  .setProtocol("http")
                                  .setHost("localhost")
                                  .setPath("/servlet")
                                  .build();
```

It's immediately clear to the developer what s/he needs to do to properly instantiate the object.

### The Factory Method design pattern

The [Factory Method design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) works somewhat similar to the Builder pattern, but it is simpler, and therefore also less flexible.

In your case, it would look as follows:

```
public class MathEquation{

    private final double number1;
    private final double number2;

    private MathEquation(final double number1, final double number2) {
        this.number1 = number1*2;
        this.number2 = number2*2;
    }

    public static createWithNumber1(final double number) {
        return new MathEquation(number, 0.0d);
    }

    public static createWithNumber2(final double number) {
        return new MathEquation(0.0d, number);
    }

    // getter methods go here
}
```

In which case you can call your code as follows:

```
final MathEquation m = MathEquation.createWithNumber1(100.0d);
```

or

```
final MathEquation m = MathEquation.createWithNumber2(100.0d);
```

A lot simpler, but it's not possible to set both numbers this way.

### The use of private constructors

You'll notice that I'm using private constructors in my code. This will force the developer that is using your class to use the static methods that you provide to construct the object. This way, you can ensure that your code is used as it is intended to and leave no doubt about how to use it.